# Microgrids in Alaska

Tags: power-supply, power, microgrid

I was looking to survey some microgrids and I couldn't get the following information. 
Are the microgrids commissioned in Alaska DC, AC or a hybrid topology? And is the transmission system used just the traditional AC or LVDC/MVDC?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Comment: @Andyaka of course I did. I was not able to ascertain what type of distribution they used. I was hoping someone from the place can shed more light on the microgrid topology.

Comment: Well I tried googling a minute ago and it told me that hybrid tech (one of your questions) was being used so maybe you want to try a little harder.

Comment: @Andyaka Can you please share me the link? Because I was only able to see two microgrids which are AC. And since they use a lot of renewable energy, are they also using LVDC/MVDC.